# How to assign several tasks among 3 CPU

Tags: c#, scheduling

if there are 3 CPUs.

> CPU 1 has got 60 sec.
>   CPU 2 has got 20 sec.
>   CPU 3 has got 15 sec.

and there are some processes to be executed.
Suppose

> t1 : 20 sec
>   t2 : 15 sec
>
> t3 : 10 sec
>   t4 : 30 sec
>
> t5 : 30 sec
>   t6 : 20 sec
>
> t7 : 20 sec
>   t8 : 35 sec
>
> t9 : 20 sec
>   t10 : 15 sec

How to assign these many tasks among 3 CPUs so that
the CPU idle time should be Least.

Comment: I have assign these these tasks to CPUs o that that idle time of CPU is least. its scheduling problem. it is a coding questions.

Comment: it is not a homework!!it is part of my task.

Comment: Are you using C# to program this?

Comment: Can I ask how in C# you assign a task to a CPU?  This sure seems like it should be tagged problem or homework to me.

Comment: How can the different CPUs "have" different amounts of time? If one CPU has 60 seconds, and the other has 30, does that mean that one exists 30 seconds into the future relative to the other?

Answer (score 1):

Simply: YOU DO NOT.

or:

The OS handles this.Different processes / Threads get automatically scheduled to use the CPU. This is core part of the OS level scheduler.

Comment: Do you know any algorithm using which threads get scheduled automatically to use CPU?

Comment: The OS will automatically do it for you... Besides you would need, in  case you code it yourself, an extra thread to check CPUs load and assign each thread to a specific CPU (which only consumes more time at the end).

Comment: -1 OP asked for a c# way to spread work over several CPU's. There are perfectly good abstractions for that in the .Net Framework

Comment: Actually no, there are NOT perfectly good abstractions. It simply is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET classes to help you with that are in the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx):